# Broken typescript intellisense with web workers in VS Code

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, web-worker

So I have a typescript/React project in VS Code where I have several different browser apps plus a web worker. The web worker needs different typings from the React apps. By having separate tsconfig.json files in each app, and the web worker folder, I can successfully build and run the project. However, the VS Code intellisense is broken in the web worker code - it is still looking up types in `lib.dom.d.ts`, which is incorrect. [This article](https://www.antonmata.me/2017-04-04-web-workers-playing-nice-with-visual-studio-code%E2%80%99s-intellisense/) appears to offer a solution to exactly this problem, but I have adopted exactly the approach it prescribes, putting separate tsconfigs in each folder, without a tsconfig in the root, and the intellisense still doesn't work properly.

Folder structure is roughly:

```
- src
  -app1
    tsconfig.json
  -app2 
    tsconfig.json
  -worker
    tsconfig.json
```

I have not included the actual content of the tsconfigs themselves, because I know them to be correct, since the typescript all compiles perfectly when I build. It's just vscode that does not seem to pick up the correct tsconfig when I am looking at web worker code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that VSCode ignores an tsconfig.json file if it is invalid, and it turns out that while it was accepted in my build process, there was a problem with the tsconfig, namely that I had specified `"files":[./*.ts]`, but `files` only takes actual file paths, not globs. This did not cause a problem in build because `tsify` (browserify plugin) ignores the `files` entry in tsconfig!

Answer (score 2):

As an altenative to the accepted answer you can use Typescript's [triple-Slash Directives](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html)

For example:

```js
/// <reference lib="WebWorker"/>
```

This is useful if there is a single file out of the tsconfig scope.